# How to tell if encryption has been enabled for my gmail email account when connecting via mac Mail / iOS Mail /

Tags: ios, macos, gmail

Ive got several gmail and google apps for business accounts setup on my laptop (macbook pro running OSX 10.10) and iPhone (running iOS9). For both devices i use Apples native Mail programme / app connecting to gmail / google apps via imap / smtp.

As i understand gmail / google apps for business has the ability to encrypt the incoming imap and outgoing smtp. How can i tell if this has been enabled on my accounts ?

Comment: Are you talking about encryption for the connection (e.g., SSL) or encryption of the message contents (e.g., GPG)?

Comment: encryption for the connection, so that if we where on a public wifi network the message couldnt be 'sniffed'

Comment: If I remember correctly this should be enabled by default with apple products?

Answer (score 2):

For the connection: Check to see what ports you're connecting to the IMAP server on. Typically 993 is the encrypted inbound port (**imap**) and 465 is the encrypted outbound port (**smtp**).

*Note: 143 (in) / 25 (out) would be the unencrypted counterparts.*

*P.S. For the truly paranoid: Run wireshark while fetching new mail.*

Comment: Using 143 or 25 (or rather 587) doesn't mean it's unencrypted. IMAP and SMTP allow to start unencrypted and immediatly upgrade the connection using the STARTTLS command. Everything following it will be encrypted.

Comment: STARTTLS isn't always the selected negotiation method nor the default.